# Count for multiple value in table without union all in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have validationErrors with various WIPReason associated with and I want to count based on different WIPReason, I am using Union All and it works but Query is very big with mutiple wip reason more than 10. Please find the query below

```
SELECT       
    COUNT(tlv.TransactionLineId) AS TotalErrors,
    COUNT(tl.Id) AS TotalLines,
    COUNT(tlv.Reason) AS NoWorkRecords,
    0 AS ValidationErrors
FROM
    dbo.TimesheetCellTransactionLine tctl
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLine tl ON tctl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLineValidation tlv ON tl.Id = tlv.TransactionLineId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WIPReason w ON tlv.Reason = w.Id
WHERE 
    tl.CurrentStatus = 1
    AND w.Id = 4 -- NoWorkRecords
GROUP BY 
    tlv.TransactionLineId, tl.Id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    COUNT(tlv.TransactionLineId) AS TotalErrors,
    COUNT(tl.Id) AS TotalLines,
    0 AS NoWorkRecords,
    COUNT(tlv.Reason) AS ValidationErrors
FROM
    dbo.TimesheetCellTransactionLine tctl
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLine tl ON tctl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLineValidation tlv ON tl.Id = tlv.TransactionLineId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WIPReason w ON tlv.Reason = w.Id
WHERE 
    tl.CurrentStatus = 1
    AND w.Id = 1 -- validationErrors
GROUP BY 
    tlv.TransactionLineId, tl.Id
```

Is there any other elegant way of doing this for  w.Id = 1 to 10

> AND w.Id = 1 -- validationErrors

Update : 
I want result as columns 10 count columns as I am using this in another big select.

Comment: try partition by w.id

Comment: Add `w.Id` to the `select` list, `and w.Id >= 1 and w.Id <= 10` to the `where` clause in place of `AND w.Id = 4` if you need to limit the range, and `w.Id` to the appropriate spot in the `group by`. You may also want to add an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement inside `count` like this:

```
SELECT       
    COUNT(tlv.TransactionLineId) AS TotalErrors,
    COUNT(tl.Id) AS TotalLines,
    COUNT(case when w.Id = 4 then tlv.Reason else null end) AS NoWorkRecords,
    COUNT(case when w.Id = 1 then tlv.Reason else null end) AS ValidationErrors,
    ... Repeat for remaining w.Id's ...
FROM
    dbo.TimesheetCellTransactionLine tctl
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLine tl ON tctl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TransactionLineValidation tlv ON tl.Id = tlv.TransactionLineId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.WIPReason w ON tlv.Reason = w.Id
WHERE 
    tl.CurrentStatus = 1
GROUP BY 
    tlv.TransactionLineId, tl.Id
```

---

**Note**
Since you are using an `inner join on tl.Id = tlv.TransactionLineId`

1. `TotalErrors/TotalLines` are always going to be the same
2. Grouping by `tl.Id` and `tlv.TransactionLineId` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(tlv.TransactionLineId) OVER (partition by (w.Id)  order by w.Id) AS TotalErrors,
       COUNT(tl.Id) OVER (partition by (w.Id)  order by w.Id) AS TotalLines,
       0 AS NoWorkRecords,
       COUNT(tlv.Reason) OVER (partition by (w.Id)  order by w.Id)  AS ValidationErrors
FROM dbo.TimesheetCellTransactionLine tctl
     INNER JOIN dbo.TransactionLine tl ON tctl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
     INNER JOIN dbo.TransactionLineValidation tlv ON tl.Id = tlv.TransactionLineId
     INNER JOIN dbo.WIPReason w ON tlv.Reason = w.Id
WHERE tl.CurrentStatus = 1
      AND w.Id between 1 and 10 -- validationErrors
GROUP BY tlv.TransactionLineId,
         tl.Id,tlv.Reason
```

Comment: This will give me 10 rows - what I want is 10 columns as count because I am using this query in another big select.

Comment: you should pivot the rows to columns, and that should be easy enough